# Blocked loading mixed active content "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900"

Tags: html, css

I updated my web site to work with SSL certificate. But now I get error

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900"
```

This code is the problem:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900);
```

What are the options to fix this?

For example can i download the file somehow?

Comment: try to remove `http:` from the url (just leave `//fonts...`)

Comment: It's now working. CSS stylesheet is not downloaded.

Answer (score 18):

Just replace **http://** with **https://** like this:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900);

Comment: Yes, I tried but it turns out that if use the web site without SSL the CSS code is not working.

Comment: How I can download the CSS from Google?

Comment: Do you mean css for font? If yes then you can download it from here:
https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: If this happens just because you load the font as a link, like:
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family...
then just remove the http: part, so it ends up like:
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family...

Comment: My site is set up with an SSL certificate so the simple switch from http to https worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

just remove that protocol prefix from url will do, like:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900);
```